# writing dictionary in a csv file : adding column name

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I would like to add headers, and then add keys  for the first column and values for the second

how can i do that , i tried this :

```
d = {}

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_file.readline()
    for line in csv_file:
        token = line.split(';')
        try:
            d[token[0]] = token[1]
        except:
            print(line)
#print(d)


CSV ="\n".join([k+';'+v for k,v in d.items()])
w=csv.DictWriter(open("sortie.csv", "w"), fieldnames =["clé","verbatim","tag","lemme","scorePos","scoreNeu","scoreNeg"],delimiter = ';') 
w.writeheader() 
w.writerow(CSV)
```

result is :

```
import TreeTagger OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CSV_dico.py", line 47, in <module>
    w.writerow(CSV)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: I think `';'.join(v)` should just be `v`. You're treating the value string as a sequence of letters and joining that sequence with `;`.

Comment: You might also want to think about what to do when your value contains a literal `;`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard    thanks , I would like to add headers , how can i do that , i treid this :     CSV ="\n".join([k+';'+v for k,v in d.items()]) 
w=csv.DictWriter(open("sortie.csv", "w"), fieldnames = ["clé","verbatim","tag","lemme","scorePos","scoreNeu","scoreNeg"],delimiter = ';')
w.writeheader()
w.writerow(CSV)     ; but it is not working any idea ?

Comment: You can [edit] your question and post code, it's much easier to read that way. What exactly is not working? Wrong output or error message?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) is expecting its input. You're trying to pass it the entire CSV as a single row.

Actually, since you've already generated the whole CSV, you can just manually write the header, then manually write the rows:

```
with open("sortie.csv", "w") as output:
    output.write("clé;verbatim;tag;lemme;scorePos;scoreNeu;scoreNeg\n")
    output.write(CSV)
```

Comment: thank you and if i want to add   to this file another key and value from another dictionnary   how can I do that : I suppose I have to write from the row at index 2 : column name "tag"  but I do not know how to do that